# JAVA: How to stop fetching data from API when thread is interrupted?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, runnable

When i click on start button i get data from twiter api

Clicking on the cancel button interrupts the thread but i still get data from twitter api.

How do i stop getting data from twitter api when thread is interrupted?

TryuingRunncabble Class:

```
public class TryuingRunabble implements Runnable {

    ConnectTwitter coT;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        coT = new ConnectTwitter();
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(3000);
            coT.searchtwitter();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException | IOException
                | TwitterException | SQLException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

MainControll Class:

```
TryuingRunabble r = new TryuingRunabble();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    start.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e)->{
        r.run();    
    });


    stop.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e)->{
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to interrupt the `Thread` running  `TryuingRunabble` :

```
    TryuingRunabble r = new TryuingRunabble();
    Thread t = new Thread(r);

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        start.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e)->{
            t.start();
        });


        stop.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (e)->{
            t.interrupt();
        });
    }
```

Comment: It works only if i click on start button and then immediately on cancel button. help?

Comment: If you really want to kill the thread, you can replace  `t.interrupt()` with`t.stop()`, but this is not suggested. @ProgrammingLycan

Comment: I tried it with stop() and it worked. Thanks but isn't there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: If the thread is sleeping, it can be interrupted immediatelly; if it is working on something such as  `coT.searchtwitter()`, I do not know other way to kill it.

Comment: @ProgrammingLycan Do not use `Thread.stop()`. You can really only cancel a running thread if the method it is executing is written to cooperate with cancellation: I have no idea if the Twitter API you are using does this or not (I am not familiar with that API.) Read [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/index.html) on interrupting threads. (The article is old, but still very useful.)

Comment: @James_D I am only using it temporarily until i find a better solution. Thank you for the link. I will check it out